# deleting all pods in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

is there a difference between deleting all pods in a daployment or doing a rollout restart of the deployment?
Of course with no changes in the deployment configuration.

Thanx

Comment: As your question is related to k8s, finding an answer here [might be difficult](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes/), as not many people seem to able to answer k8s-related questions. You would have better luck asking this on another StackExchange site dedicated for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I would always do a k rollout restart deploy <name-of-the-deploy> instead of using a delete, the restart command will gracefully terminate all pods in your deployment and bring up new ones.